# Removing PARTS of elements in list - Python

Tags: python, list, del

```
my_list = ("12/30/19 14:01", "11/20/19 08:10", "03/13/19 19:30")
```

Desired output:

```
new_list = ("12", "11", "03")
```

I want to remove everything except the month(first two integers).

With only one element in the list, this method works:

```
new_list = my_list[:-12]
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Your list is not a list but a tuple.

Comment: One option: `new_list = tuple(dt[:2] for dt in my_list)`

Comment: "With only one element in the list, this method works: `new_list = my_list[:-12]`" no it doesnt. If `my_list` were a list (or tuple) wiht one element, them `my_list[:-12]` would return an *empty list*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_list = list(map(lambda x: x[:2], my_list))
```

Comment: You could also map `operator.itemgetter(slice(0,2))`. for larger collections you will notice the efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using python list comp, as follows:

```
my_list = ("12/30/19 14:01", "11/20/19 08:10", "03/13/19 19:30")
new_list = tuple([x[:2] for x in my_list])
```

The output of new_list should look like below:

```
('12', '11', '03')
```

Comment: No need for the brackets. You're making a list then turning it into a tuple